# Mysql: How to get values from other table base from an id

Tags: mysql

Assuming that I have 3 tables on my database

```
Table:Category   
   category_id

Table:container   
   container_id
   category_id

Table:products

   container_id
   product_id
```

How do you get all product_id based on a category_id?

For example I have these data inside my tables from above:

```
Table: category
    sour
    sweet
    Bitter


Table: container
    bottled
    sachet

Table: product
    sugar
    vinegar
    cocoa
```

How do you get all Product(`tb_product`) where category(`tb_category`) is sweet

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to solve your problem.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    products a
        INNER JOIN container b
            on a.container_id = b.container_ID
        INNER JOIN Category c
            ON b.category_ID = c.categoryID
WHERE   c.categoryName = 'sweete'
```

As you can see, I assume that the `Category` table has columns `category_ID` and `categoryName`. So in my example above,I've use category name to search for all products that belong on certain category.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*
from Category c
join container c2 on c2.category_id = c.category_id
join product p on p.container_id = c2.container_id
where c.name = 'sweet';
```

Note the order of the tables in the query (which should perform faster than the other answer!)

Comment: sir i do have question for you, as far as I Know the order of execution is `FROM...WHERE...GROUP BY..` so the server do all the joining first before the filtering right? how will you prove that joining `category to container to product` is faster that `product to container to category`? I need to know this cause I do joining alot :) thank you sir.

Comment: @UnhandledException because the first table listed has the where clause condition acting on it. Otherwise, you have to join all the way down through the tables before you can filter on the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inner join like this:

```
SELECT a.product_id FROM products AS a INNER JOIN  container AS b on a.container_id = b.container_Id INNER JOIN Category AS c on  b.category_Id = c.category_id where c.category_id = 'new'
```